# Print output of count to DBMS

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I'm trying to run the same query over and over again so I can get the status of a process.

How do I use PL/SQL and the DBMS window or just the Query Result window to accomplish this?

My query looks like this:

```
Select count(table1.*) from table1
inner join table2 on table1.fk = table2.fk
inner join table3 on table3.fk = table2.fk
where 
table1.col2={a value}
```

I've looked at several answers which discussed using a loop or dbms.output.put_line() but can't get my court to be what's displayed.

Sample data of info in these tables:

table1.columnName has company IDs and a program/process IDs

```
Col1 | Col2 | col3
1    | 42   | 2
2    | 42   | 2
3    | 42   | 2
1    | 41   | 2
4    | 41   | 2
1    | 43   | 2
```

Example output for the query where table1.col2=42 would be 3 because there are 3 rows where Col2 has value 42

Thank you

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Comment: Added sample data with an output

Comment: As far as i understood, you need result of the query in every minute or some defined time period? Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

in the result window just type / and hit enter and you get the new count without typing in the entire query again. 
in the pl_sql you can use a unix script and a sendmail command to get the results delivered to your inbox.

Comment: Hi Athul, thank's for repsonding. If the process take 3 hours, I'd rather not sit by my computer for 3 hours pushing a button. 

I also don't have write access to the database (or even a connected system) so I don't think I could request an email be sent.